# Date as a filter in vector format on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to use date as a filter in zone on GEE script and I want to add start and end date as date filter. I need to add start date and end date in here. But vectors format is different from Raster format. Can you help me please?

---

```
Map.addLayer(latest_radd_alert.select('Date'), {min:20001,max:21200,palette:['eb1677','f6f5ff', '0000FF']}, 'RADD alert date')

var year21sel = latest_radd_alert.select('Date');
var zones = year21sel.gt(20001).add(year21sel.gt(21001));
zones = zones.updateMask(zones.neq(0));' enter code'
```

---